# Changing table engine while low on disk space

Tags: mysql, database

my table size is about 9GB and I have 4GBs left of space

When changing the table engine, the table is copied to a temp engine.

Would this process work if I'm low on space?

Comment: no, unless the new engine is massively more efficient at storing the data. it's basically copying your data and changing a few "scaffolding" bytes around the raw data. so you need (most likely) at LEAST as much space the data files originally occupy, plus extra so the rest of the system doesn't trip over itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the temp table created during alter table is kept in the same location as the original file ( usually /var/lib/mysql/{db_name}/{table_name.XXX} ). And for the same reason the alter table should fail with out of disk error( error code: 28).